Why \IfPackageAtLeastTF{⟨package⟩}{⟨date⟩}{\PassOptionsToPackage{⟨option⟩}{⟨package⟩}}{} doesn't pass ⟨option⟩ to ⟨package⟩?
My current version of parskip is 2021-03-14 so:
\IfPackageAtLeastTF{parskip}{2018-08-24}{\PassOptionsToPackage{indent}{parskip}}{}
\usepackage{parskip}

should pass the indent option to parskip. But it is not the case as pointed out by the following MCE where the paragraphs aren't indented (in the real use case, I need this conditional, not for a document, but for a package). Why?
\documentclass{article}
\IfPackageAtLeastTF{parskip}{2018-08-24}{\PassOptionsToPackage{indent}{parskip}}{}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}


Because \IfPackageAtLeastTF returns false if the package isn't loaded. LaTeX cannot know the version of the package unless it has been loaded.

@cfr that looks like an answer to me

@cfr Okay. So no way to load a package with a given option if and only if the package is recent enough to provide this option?

@DenisBitouzé no built in way in LaTeX. You could of course read the file and search for a package version before executing it, though that comes with a whole lot of new problems.

you could append or prepend the option to the class options list: \RequirePackage{etoolbox} \preto\@classoptionslist{indent}\makeatother. But personally I wouldn't care. How probable is it that someone uses your new class from 2024 (which probably uses hooks and so requires a rather new LaTeX) with a parindent from before 2021?

@UlrikeFischer It is an old package, and not one of mine :)

LaTeX only knows the version of a package (or class) once it is loaded. Before that the conditional used by \IfPackageAtLeastTF... returns false. Hence the fourth argument of
\IfPackageAtLeastTF{parskip}{2018-08-24}{\PassOptionsToPackage{indent}{parskip}}{}

is executed irrespective of parskip's version. In this case, you could use
\IfFileExists{parskip-2001-04-09.sty}{\PassOptionsToPackage{indent}{parskip}}{}

